# My (previously pad trained) dog pees and poops in the house when I am at work

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have a 10 year old Jack Russell Terrier/Chihuahua mix. He is trained to go on his pee pad which he uses while I am at the house, or he lets me know when he needs to go outside.

Just recently he has started peeing elsewhere in the house when I am at work. Also he poops in the house in my son's room and not on his pee pad (at night). What do I need to do to get him to consistently pee on the pad?

I do have other pets (birds and guinea pigs) but I don't think he would be marking his territory because he is peeing not close to these animals.

Comment: Is this a new problem, or has he always done this? If new, have you asked your vet? Breaking training can be a sign of medical condition. If he always did this, then he was never housetrained

Comment: @jalynn2 The jackrussell is10yrs old, no reason it is still peeing and pooping in the house. It could be a dysfunction/disorder, perhaps depression that causes the dog to poop the floor or perhaps the dogs age which I calculated and I think the dog is 70. Okay a 70 year old dog as science proves "dogs are similar to humans physically and mentally". As a human gets old they try to keep there mental state in control however not always can the mental state be in control. The possibility that the brain could be giving up mentally on the dog is not a good thing. Yes, the dog should go to the "vet".

Comment: No he hasn't always done this. Just started recently..

Comment: Rhonda, I edited your question to make it easier to read and attract more attention. If I accidentally changed the meaning of your question, please use the edit function to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Once a dog breaks house training, they have certain spots they will poop or pee in and they'll continue to use the same spot (or very near it) unless you do something to stop them. They make deterrents for peeing such as [this](http://www.natures-miracle.com/products/pet-odor-stain-removers/stop-cat-dog-marking.aspx) but what is probably going to be most useful is to either kennel your dog or shut him in a smaller space with a pee pad such as a bathroom or a bedroom. Since he's older (less energy) and he's such a small dog, closing him in a smaller space shouldn't be much of a problem for him.

The fact that he's older shouldn't have too much to do with it since he's a smaller dog and smaller dogs usually live longer (the higher end of the life expectancy is 16 years for a Jack Russell and 18 for a chihuahua). And the fact that he's peeing AND pooping makes it less likely that it's a medical issue (if he was only peeing, it might suggest that he had a bladder infection or kidney problems, etc)